# Create a new application in ns-2: fail to transmit any packet

Tags: c++, networking, tcl, simulator

I'd like to ask for your help on creating a user-defined application in ns-2.

I tried to create a new application for simulating scheduling policies by modifying the code of CBR traffic application.

I've finished c++ files and tried to do the simulation with the oTcl script. When I run the ns, it turns out that the application does not transmit any packet. To make sure that my Tcl script is correct, I change the application to CBR and then the program can indeed transmit packets.

It seems that the Tcl commands could not access the functions which I define in the c++ domain.

Should I do anything else in the oTcl domain?
I'm wondering if there is anyone who has ever came across the similar situation.

The following are what I've done so far:

1. Create a new application class in c++ domain.
2. Create a static shadow object by deriving from TclClass
3. Create instprocs by defining the function "`int command(argc, argv)`" in c++ domain.
4. In oTcl domain: define an instproc `init` and use `-superclass` to declare that the new application is a derived class from "Application" class.

Thank you very much for your generous help.